# .env constants not readable in React project

Tags: reactjs, environment, dotenv

I have a an issue trying to get constants our of my `.env` file in a React app. My app structure is pretty basic:

```
my-react-app/
|- .env
|- .gitignore
|- .prettierrc
|- node-modules/
|- public/
|- src/
   |- Base.js
   |- App.js
|- package.json
|- yarn.lock
|- README.md
```

I'm using `react-scripts` version "3.2.0"

The `.env` looks like this:

```
# .env
# Auto-logout values
REACT_APP_LOGOUT_PERIOD_MINS=15
```

and the `Base.js` file looks like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' })
console.log(process.env)

export const LOGOUT_PERIOD_MINS = process.env.REACT_APP_LOGOUT_PERIOD_MINS
```

What I get from the `console.log()` call in `Base.js`  is:

```
{NODE_ENV: "development", PUBLIC_URL: ""}
```

I've tried putting Base inside the root directory, which errors because it's outside `src`. I've tried with and without the `path` config setting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried re-starting your react app from a completely new terminal window? 9/10 when an env var isn't available it's because of something like this. Worth a shot.

Comment: That was it. D'oh. Turn it on and off again. Feel like an idiot. Please stick it in a separate answer so I can accept it Jamie ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you'll probably wanna close your terminal window and re-run `yarn start` from a fresh terminal. 9/10 this is the reason for env vars not showing up. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to require dotenv in CRA, it should work without it. Importing it explicitly and setting the path might be overriding the default CRA .env setup.

Comment: Yep, I tried using no path, and also removing the `require`... :-(

Comment: BTW, after realising that it was not restarting the process manually (and relying on hot-loading) I test whether I needed the `require` & `path` combo... you were right, I didn't. But I couldn't see that because I hadn't manually restarted.